# Typeerror: Destructuring error for firebase user

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

Hey im new to react native and I tried to authenticate the user for sign in so I initaialized the firebase and I want to  direct the user to different stacks based on the user. If user is undefined to one stack if not to the other but I get this error

> TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. In
> order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a
> Symbol.iterator method.

for user when I import useAuth and it says that user is not an array.

Followng is my firebase.js

```
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '-',
  authDomain: '437ac.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: '-437ac',
  storageBucket: '-437ac.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '940906',
  appId: '-',
};

// Initialize Firebase

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const app = firebase.app();
export const FreshlyyImageStore = getStorage(app);
```

Below is my useAuth.js

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from "react";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, User } from "firebase/auth";
//import { auth } from '../utils/firebase';


export function useAuth() {
    const [user, setUser] =useState<User | undefined>(undefined);
    const auth = getAuth();
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribeFromAuthStateChanged = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in, 
            setUser(user);
          } else {
            // User is signed out
            setUser(undefined);
          }
        });
        console.log(user)
        return unsubscribeFromAuthStateChanged;
      }, []);
      return { user };
    }
```

Below is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {useAuth} from '../hooks/useAuth'
import  UserStack from '../navigation/userStack';
import  AuthStack from '../navigation/authStack';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TextInput,
    ScrollView,
  } from 'react-native';
export default function RootNavigation() {
    
    const { user } = useAuth();
   
    return user ? <UserStack /> : <AuthStack />;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicate which line of code generates the error.